# NoHostAvailableException en Cassandra

Tags: java, jdbc, cassandra

Necesito hacer una presentación + conexión a Cassandra para clase. El caso es que no deja conectarme cuando uso los drivers de datastax. He dado mil vueltas porque al parecer hay versiones viejas que son incompatibles y bueno, he perdido unas cuantas horas con esto.

Mi codigo de momento luce así:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException;

public class conectaradb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
 try {
        Cluster cluster;
         Session sesion;

         cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withPort(9042).build();

         sesion= cluster.connect("ejemplodb");

         ResultSet resultado= sesion.execute("select * from empleados");
         String nombreemp,fecha,cargo;
         double comision,salario;
         int empno;

         for (Row row:resultado) {
             empno=row.getInt("empno");
             cargo=row.getString("cargo");
             comision=row.getDouble("comision");
             fecha=row.getString("fechaing");
             nombreemp=row.getString("nombreempno");
             salario=row.getDouble("salario");
             System.out.println(empno+" "+cargo+" "+comision+" "+fecha+" "+nombreemp+" "+salario);
         }  
         cluster.close();

 }catch(NoHostAvailableException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getErrors());
 }


    }

}
```

El error aparece al conectar a localhost... También he estado toqueteando el archivo .yaml, así que si alguien sabe la correcta configuración que debe tener estaría estupendo.

Comment: Por favor danos detalles de la instalacion de Cassandra a la que desea conectarse. Esta el servidor de Cassandra ejecutándose en la misma maquina que su programa?

Answer (score 1):

te resumo las posibles causas por las que te puede estar dando esto.

Cassandra se levanta y se "pega" a un interfaz de red, la que tú le indiques en el fichero cassandra.yaml en `listen_address`. Lo primero que debes tener en cuenta es que si tienes varias interfaces de red sólo va a permitir mensajes del interfaz de red al que se haya asociado. Si quieres que se asocie a todos, debes poner `0.0.0.0`.

Cuando levantas Cassandra, al menos uno de los nodos semillas deben estar levantados (o ser tu nodo un nodo semilla). Esto se especifica en la propiedad `seeds`. Si tienes una instalación de un único nodo, asegúrate que tu `listen_address` y tu `seeds` tienen el mismo valor.

Supongo por tu código que todo está corriendo en el mismo nodo (tanto programa como Cassandra), por filtrar un poco más todo, asegúrate de que tu firewall permite conexiones, y mira tu fichero hosts (/etc/hosts) para confirmar que localhost apunta a tu ip local.

Coméntanos si algo de esto ha ayudado, o sube los siguientes datos

- Dónde se ejecuta Cassandra (y su fichero cassandra.yaml)
- Dónde se ejecuta tu programa